# Regex: How to get all matches of a group in a string

Tags: regex, string, regex-group

I have the following regex

```
.*context\.Database\.SqlQuery<[A-Za-z]+>\("(?<sqlStatement>.*?[^\\])"\)
```

and I have the following string

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("select [Name] from [DomainModel] where UniqueId = 'someGuid'").Single();context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("select [Description] from [DomainModel] where UniqueId = 'someGuid'").Single();
```

I need to match all occurrences of `context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("")` and extract the string in between these paranthesis.
When I'm testing it with splitting the string like this:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("select [Name] from [DomainModel] where UniqueId = 'someGuid'").Single();
context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("select [Description] from [DomainModel] where UniqueId = 'someGuid'").Single();
```

It works fine. I need to get it working on the previous scenario and output of matches should be like this

the first match

> select [Name] from [DomainModel] where UniqueId = 'someGuid'

second match

> select [Description] from [DomainModel] where UniqueId = 'someGuid'

here is the [regexr](https://regexr.com/3ijrh) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `.*` at the very beginning. Since that can match everything, that ends up picking up all of the matches except the last one.

If you just drop that, your pattern can pick up each one.

```
context\.Database\.SqlQuery<[A-Za-z]+>\("(?<sqlStatement>.*?[^\\])"\)
```

Comment: I was mistaken in testing, it's working fine thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with `.*` 
Since `.` matches with any character except new line.
and `*` quntifies regex to matchs between zero and many times.

You just need to remove `.*` from the start of given regex.
[Here](https://regexr.com/3iju2) is working example of given problem

Comment: thanks for the effort and comprehensive answer, it did solve the issue with @samanine's answer